# Ganache-cli unable to create database to store blockchain

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, ganache-cli

I am new to smart contracts, web3. I am trying to deploy a smart contract to ganache-cli and store the blockchain in a database. When I run the below code I am able to deploy the contract but unable to create the database and store blockchain. I am getting no errors. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the deploy code

`const ganache    = require('ganache-cli');` 
`const { Web3 }   = require('web3');` 
`const {abi, evm} = require('./compile');`

`const options = { database: {db_path: 'my/path/to/db'} };`

`const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider(options));` 
`const deploy = async () => {` 
`const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();` 
`console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);` 
`const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)` 
`.deploy({data: evm.bytecode.object})` 
`.send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 5000000 });` 
`console.log("Contract deployed to", result.options.address);`
`};` 
`deploy();`